# Extracting a .tar file returns, “This does not look like a tar archive.”

Tags: linux, tar, webarchive

I'm trying to download a dataset from [here](https://data.mendeley.com/datasets/v88xfw5wyx/1) for my machine learning project
the data file appears to be tar but not extracting properly.

```
tar -xvf SNAKE_ALL.tar
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

tried

```
gzip -dc SNAKE_ALL.tar | tar -xf -
gzip: SNAKE_ALL.tar: not in gzip format
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

and

```
file SNAKE_ALL.tar
SNAKE_ALL.tar: HTML document, ASCII text
```

link to data:https://data.mendeley.com/datasets/v88xfw5wyx/1

Comment: It's telling you it's an HTML document.  Just use less and you will see its contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a tar file. The download fails and the ".tar" file you get is really a html fail saying:

"

403 Forbidden

## Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /public/snake_toxins/SNAKE_ALL.tar
on this server.

---

Apache/2.2.15 (Linux/SUSE) mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.0 PHP/5.3.3 Server at www.cbs.dtu.dk Port 80
"

Next time you get something like this run the commman:

file SNAKE_ALL.tar to see what kind of file it really is.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be corrupted. Note that the file size is 0 bytes.

[file screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxRlT.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `curl -JLO` to download the file. With `curl -O` it just downloads an HTML file sometimes.

Comment: Hi Raf, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please specify the specific `curl -JLO` command you are suggesting be used? The command you suggest appears to also just download an HTML file, so this answer is incorrect in answering the original question.